# Locating printf object/module

Tags: linux, kernel, printf, perf

I would like to know which kernel module is called when `printf` is executed in my C code. How can I find that? Let's say, when I use `ldd` I can find which libraries are attached to my binary file. I am looking for something similar. Basically, I want to study the **structure of the file** that is responsible for printf.

Consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int N = 100;
  while (i++ <= N) {
    printf("%d ", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the perf command `perf record -e cycles -j any -a -o perf.data ./test`, I see the following output in the data file

```
# Overhead  Command  Source Shared Object  Source Symbol                           Target Symbol                           Basic Blo
# ........  .......  ....................  ......................................  ......................................  .........
#
    21.19%  swapper  [unknown]             [k] 0000000000000000                    [k] 0000000000000000                    -
    10.98%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] __intel_pmu_enable_all              [k] native_write_msr                    -
    10.66%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] intel_pmu_lbr_enable_all            [k] __intel_pmu_enable_all              -
    10.66%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] native_write_msr                    [k] intel_pmu_lbr_enable_all            -
     5.00%  perf     [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] smp_call_function_single            [k] smp_call_function_single            -
     3.14%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] acpi_os_read_memory                 [k] acpi_os_read_memory                 -
     2.23%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] intel_idle                          [k] intel_idle                          -
     1.88%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] sched_clock                         [k] native_sched_clock                  -
     1.82%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] native_sched_clock                  [k] sched_clock                         -
     1.15%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] nmi_handle                          [k] sched_clock                         -
     1.15%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] native_set_fixmap                   [k] native_set_fixmap                   -
     1.09%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] sched_clock                         [k] nmi_handle                          -
     0.82%  swapper  [kernel.vmlinux]      [k] __x86_indirect_thunk_rax            [k] __x86_indirect_thunk_rax            -
  ...
  ...
```

So, where is module/file associated with `printf`? What does the first line mean in the output of perf?

Let's say, I want to profile `printf`, the code that is executed to put something on the screen.

UPDATE:

The following output shows that my test program is linked to a custom glibc version which I have recompiled from source with options that I want.

```
$ ldd test
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe26875000)
        libc.so.6 => /opt/glibc-2.23-install/libc.so.6 (0x00007f28196d5000)
        /opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2819a76000)
```

Comment: `printf` is part of the standard C library. You want to profile `glibc`? Do you have a variant of the library compiled for profiling?

Comment: Yes, I have that. Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 1):

None of the events you’re looking at come from your `test` program; you need to find a line with `test` in the “Command” field, and zoom into that. With some luck (because `perf record` samples), you’ll then see entries like

```
   1.31%  590585  libc-2.30.so       [.] __vfprintf_internal                         [.] __vfprintf_internal
   0.18%  590585  libc-2.30.so       [.] _itoa_word                                  [.] _itoa_word
   0.18%  590585  libc-2.30.so       [.] __vfprintf_internal                         [.] _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   0.18%  590585  libc-2.30.so       [.] _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5                [.] __vfprintf_internal
   0.18%  590585  libc-2.30.so       [.] __strchrnul_avx2                            [.] __strchrnul_avx2
```

etc., showing the calls from `test` (`590585` in my traces) into the C library which correspond to your `printf` calls.

`printf` is mostly implemented in the C library, so you won’t find much of relevance in the kernel. Running your program with `strace` will produce something like

```
...
write(1, "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14"..., 2961 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 ) = 296
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The only output-related system call in your program is a single `write`: the C library buffers its output, so all your `printf` calls append to a buffer, and that buffer is flushed in a single call when the program exits.

If you want to see how `printf` is implemented in the GNU C library, look at the source code in `stdio-common`, starting with [`printf.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/printf.c). To profile `printf` itself, you’d probably be better served by `gprof`.

Comment: But I don't see such calls in my perf data file. I have uploaded it at https://gofile.io/d/YDd8ph What is the perf command that you used?

Comment: One more thing. Is `write()` part of the libc or kernel then?

Comment: I ran `perf record -F max -e cycles -j any -a ./590585` (so you’d run `perf record -F max -e cycles -j any -a ./test`). Remember that `perf` *samples* in this configuration; if it doesn’t happen to sample at a point where execution is inside a `printf`-related function, you won’t see anything relevant in the traces. `write()` is a function in the C library which forwards to a system call in the kernel.

Comment: I added `-F max` and got a bigger file. But really, there is no `__vfprintf_internal`. Something is crazy here. My data file is at https://gofile.io/d/Rk0Xrv

Comment: You might need to try several times. I can’t help you by looking at your data file, it’s only valid with your binaries (everything matching `perf buildid-list perf.data`).

Comment: Maybe more iterations or using `\n` to force flush the output. Do you agree?

Comment: NO. I even tried with N=10000 and `printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d \n", i, i, i, i, i, i);` and tried many times with `cycles -j any -a` and `cycles:u -j any,u -a` and `cycles:k -j any,k -a`. I don't see `__vfprintf_internal`

Comment: Don’t look specifically for `__vfprintf_internal`; look for `printf`-like calls. Since you’re using version 2.23, you’ll only see `vfprintf`, `itoa` variants etc.

Comment: Right I see `vfprintf`.